Adjusting the numbering of the results in a thesis depending on whether the section has subsections or not
I'm writing my MSc thesis as a document class book. I have this portion of code in the preamble
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
 \ifnum\value{section}=0 
  \thechapter% "no section"
 \else
  \thesection% at least within a section
\fi%
.\arabic{theorem}}

This code simply makes the numbering of the theorems (propositions, corollaries, definition, etc) depends on whether the chapter has sections or not, e.g. if chapter 1 does not have any section, then the numbering goes like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... and so on. If chapter 2 has a section x, say, then the numbering goes like 2.x.1, 2.x.2, 2.x.3, ... and so. Now, I'm in a situation which requires some section to have subsections. Unfortunately, this code does not work properly if the section has subsections. I mean if, for instance, section x of chapter 2 has a subsection y (say), then the numbering inside the subsection y goes like 2.x.1 instead of 2.x.y.1.
Is it possible to modify this code and treat this case?

Did you define the theorem environment via \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]? Please advise.

Not tested, but probably an extension of your piece of code to subsection
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
 \ifnum\value{section}=0 
  \thechapter% "no section"
 \else
   \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 
     \thesection%
   \else
     \thesubsection%
  \fi
\fi%
.\arabic{theorem}}

should work.

It worked. Thank you.

You haven't indicated how you've defined the theorem environment. If you did so via
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

then the following redefinition of \thetheorem achieves your formatting objective:
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \thesubsection%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{section}>0 
      \thesection%
    \else
      \thechapter
    \fi%
  \fi%
  .\arabic{theorem}%
}

